# What exactly is a Hamiltonian telescope? Is this one?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, history, optics, terminology

[This comment](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33337/why-is-this-telescope-so-short-how-hard-is-it-to-make-such-a-fast-primary#comment63049_33347) on the current answer to *Why is this telescope so short? How hard is it to make such a fast primary?* says

> In this [forum topic](https://astronomy.ru/forum/index.php/topic,175643.0.html) Borisov appears to call it an f/1.5 Hamiltonian.

Wikipedia's [Catadioptric system; Catadioptric dialytes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catadioptric_system#Catadioptric_dialytes) says:

> Catadioptric dialytes are the earliest type of catadioptric telescope. **They consist of a single-element refracting telescope objective combined with a silver-backed negative lens (similar to a Mangin mirror). The first of these was the Hamiltonian telescope patented by W. F. Hamilton in 1814.** The Schupmann medial telescope designed by German optician Ludwig Schupmann near the end of the 19th century placed the catadioptric mirror beyond the focus of the refractor primary and added a third correcting/focusing lens to the system.

The image of the telescope in the linked question shows a very short and squat telescope with a 65 cm aperture that does not appear to have a "single-element refracting telescope objective", so I am confutes!

**Questions:**

1. What (the heck) is and is not a proper Hamiltonian telescope?
2. Is the Gennady Borisov telescope in the linked question (and [shown here](https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/possible-interstellar-comet-headed-our-way/)) one?

Comment: potentially helpful: http://www.ceravolo.com/hamilton.html

Comment: A Hamiltonian telescope is a telescope that visits each vertex of a graph exactly once.

Comment: Question: Is this telescope still used today? or has it become obsolete? I think that since it is 19th century technology, it is easily replaced by digital telescopes.

Comment: @NilayGhosh according to information [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33337/7982) and in the answer below, Gennady Borisov discovered comet G Borisov in 2019 with one, so I would say yes, it is still being used!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gennady Borisov wrote on [the astronomy.ru forum](https://astronomy.ru/forum/index.php/topic,175643.0.html):

> The first observations of the object were made in the morning of August 30 with a 650 mm telescope, F / 1.5 Hamilton

> Первые наблюдения объекта были сделаны под утро 30 августа на телескопе 650 мм, F/1.5 Гамильтоне

> Yes, this is Hamilton. All surfaces are spheres. Has a 3-lens corrector.
> Good image quality, high aperture ratio. Large field of view: on FLI ML16803  FOV:  2.1 х 2.1 deg 1.87"/pixel

> Да, это Гамильтон. Все поверхности сферы. Имеет 3-х линзовый корректор.
> Хорошее качество изображения, высокая светосила. Большое поле зрения: на матрице FLI ML16803  FOV:  2.1 х 2.1 deg 1.87"/pixel
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! I'd like to try to read further (with google translate's assistance). I tried searching the page for "Гамильтон" or "гамильтон" or "поверхности" but no success. It's not easy making a 65 cm lens with a big hole in the center; the backstory on how this was done must be interesting! Actually I will ask about how that's done in a separate question so don't answer that here :-)

Comment: [How to make a 65 cm lens with a 20 cm hole in it for a Hamiltonian telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39705/7982)

Comment: @uhoh He's not really an amateur. He is an observatory employee who builds and repairs telescopes. The optical system is made on professional equipment.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, got it. Nonetheless it will be interesting to see how such a "holy lens" (pardon the pun) can be made.